# How to update a Dataframe with two different time intervals with asyncio

Tags: python, dataframe, python-asyncio

What I'm trying to do is updating a Dataframe in two intervals of different lengths.
Update 1 changes the last row of the df with an interval of 0 - 2 seconds, generated in the `Signal` class, 
Update 2 is generated in `change_hist_data()` and alters the rows 0 - 4 in a 5 second interval.
The problem with my code is that the interval of the change of data occurs on the entire df in the speed of the `pulse` in the `Signal` class.
What I want is that row 0 - 4 updates in 5 second intervals, only the last row in the faster pace.
What am I doing wrong?
Btw, if someone likes to give me an additional tipp - will the `sys.stdout.write("\033[F")` run smoothly long term ( weeks or months) ? I notice that sometimes the column name shifts a bit back and forth

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import random
import numpy as np
import sys
import asyncio



class Signal:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def pulse(self):
        
        while True:
            x = random.uniform(0,2)
            y = random.uniform(1,9)
            time.sleep(x)
            self.pulse = y
            return self.pulse

async def change_hist_data():
    
    while True:
        
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(print_df())
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        data = np.random.rand(6,1)
        
        return data

async def print_df():
   
    while True:

        task2 = asyncio.create_task(change_hist_data())
        df = pd.DataFrame(await task2, columns={'data'})
        p = Signal()
        p = p.pulse()
        df.data.iloc[-1] = p
        print(df)
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        


asyncio.run(print_df())
```

Update:

I came up with this solution based on Peter Cornelius input and my initial idea. The `df` is now printing in both intervals. Actually the method name `random_delay` is not appropriate anymore as I set it to a fix interval of 0.2 seconds.

```
import random
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys


class DataFrameWrapper:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.data = self.update_rows0_to_4() 
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.data, columns={'data'})

    def update_row5(self):
        
        self.pulse = random.uniform(0,2) 
        return self.pulse
        
    def update_rows0_to_4(self):
        self.data = np.random.rand(6,1)
        return self.data
        
async def random_delay(df_wrapper):
    
    while True:

        df_wrapper.df.data.iloc[-1] = df_wrapper.update_row5()
        print(df_wrapper.df)
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
       
async def delay_5s(df_wrapper):

    while True:

        df_wrapper.df.data = df_wrapper.update_rows0_to_4()
        print(df_wrapper.df)
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        
        await asyncio.sleep(5.0)
    

df_wrapper = DataFrameWrapper()

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(random_delay(df_wrapper),delay_5s(df_wrapper) )

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've given a nice description of the problem, but the structure of your program isn't right.  You need something like this:

```
import random
import asyncio

class DataFrameWrapper:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def update_row5(self):
        print("Updating row 5")
        
    def update_rows0_to_4(self):
        print("Updating row 0-4")
        
async def random_delay(df_wrapper):
    while True:
        x = random.uniform(0.0, 2.0)
        await asyncio.sleep(x)
        df_wrapper.update_row5()
        
async def delay_5s(df_wrapper):
    asyncio.create_task(random_delay(df_wrapper))
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5.0)
        df_wrapper.update_rows0_to_4()
        
# df is some dataframe
df_wrapper = DataFrameWrapper(df)
asyncio.run(delay_5s(df_wrapper))
```

Here, the periodic time delay functions are two asyncio tasks.  They periodically execute function calls back to the data frame object, where you can manipulate your data.  I haven't tried to include any details there - I've just stubbed out those functions.

In your first while loop, you call time.sleep, which blocks the asyncio event loop.  So that's not a task, and therefore it will not cooperate with the coroutine change_hist_data.

Neither of your first two while loops are really loops, since you always return at the end of the loop.

Comment: I think your solution is too far away from my code structure. I don't know how to merge them. Where's the dataframe?

Comment: The dataframe is in the class I named "MockDataFrame."  If you don't move the return statements out of your first two while loops, then they aren't really loops - they will always exit at the end of your first iteration.  You notice that I don't have return statements in my 2 delay tasks - that's why they run forever and yours do not.

Comment: I really don't understand what you indent with df.update_row5(). df is supposed to be a dataframe but update_row5() is a method. I'd like to see your sketch with a dataframe instead of printing a string

Comment: I've never used dataframes but I use asyncio every day.  I was only trying to help with the design of the asyncio part of your program, which seemed to be where the problem was.  I changed the class name to "DataFrameWrapper" and showed how you can pass an actual dataframe to its constructor.  Then in the two methods you can do whatever you want with the actual dataframe.

Comment: I've found a mixed solution. What do you think? It's in my original post...

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.  I like the way you start both tasks with gather() instead of the way I did it.  However, from a design standpoint, I would move all the code that modifies the dataframe into the functions of df_wrapper, instead of returning them and relying on the calling function to modify the dataframe.  I would also do the printing inside the two df_wrapper functions instead of in the timing functions.  But that's a minor point.  Glad you have got it working now.